# grub default leads to "soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck", but menu to Advanced options, then esc, then default, boots ok

Tags: grub

Upgraded to Debian bookworm. A hard reboot starts grub. That's good.

But then waiting or hitting return to get the default grub selection leads to a "soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck".

Interestingly if I instead first select "Advanced options for Debian" in grub (i.e. the 2nd menu choice), then hit the escape key (to return to the outer menu), then select the default (Debian GNU/Linux) top menu choice and hit return I can boot normally.  Also selecting a specific advanced option boots ok.  Only the initial default hangs.

I reviewed /boot/grub/grub.cfg, but don't see anything that might cause this (I have not manually edited it):

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod btrfs
set root='hd0,msdos10'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos10 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos10  ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=4
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=4
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
insmod part_msdos
insmod btrfs
set root='hd0,msdos10'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos10 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos10  ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
fi
insmod jpeg
if background_image /boot/grub/earthlights_dmsp_big-256 RGB.jpg; then
  true
else
  set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
  set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e' {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod btrfs
    set root='hd0,msdos10'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos10 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos10  ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-13-amd64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-13-amd64 root=UUID=ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e ro initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-13-amd64
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e' {
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-13-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-13-amd64-advanced-ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod btrfs
        set root='hd0,msdos10'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos10 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos10  ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-13-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-13-amd64 root=UUID=ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e ro initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-13-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-13-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-13-amd64-recovery-ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod btrfs
        set root='hd0,msdos10'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos10 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos10  ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-13-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-13-amd64 root=UUID=ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e ro single initrd=/install/initrd.gz
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-13-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-26-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-26-amd64-advanced-ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod btrfs
        set root='hd0,msdos10'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos10 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos10  ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-26-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-26-amd64 root=UUID=ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e ro initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-26-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-26-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-26-amd64-recovery-ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod btrfs
        set root='hd0,msdos10'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos10 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos10  ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-26-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-26-amd64 root=UUID=ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e ro single initrd=/install/initrd.gz
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-26-amd64
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+x64.bin)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod btrfs
    set root='hd0,msdos10'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos10 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos10  ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
    fi
        linux   /boot/memtest86+x64.bin
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+x64.bin, serial console)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod btrfs
    set root='hd0,msdos10'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos10 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos10  ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed95d75a-0770-4094-aba5-898678f22b0e
    fi
        linux   /boot/memtest86+x64.bin console=ttyS0,115200
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 10 (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-0F78EF80D892D51E' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0F78EF80D892D51E
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0F78EF80D892D51E
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-C08B3562685C8C00' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  C08B3562685C8C00
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root C08B3562685C8C00
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: There should be a stack trace after the "soft lockup" message - can you get a copy of it? For example, by first triggering the error, then rebooting and running `journalctl -b -1` ("show log of the previous boot"), then pressing Shift-G to go into the very end of the log and then scrolling backwards with arrow keys? The stack trace should at least reveal what kind of activity caused the hang (ACPI, disk access, USB access, something else?)